# What IP address should I pass to a python server program to get it running on AWS EC2?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, amazon-ec2, server

I want to run a python server program on AWS from my computer. Usually, I run python server locally using the format **program.py host IP**: ex

my_server.py 127.0.0.1 8888

When I try the assigned IP from EC2 (ip-**172-xx-xx-xxx**), I got the following error :

OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

Any clues about what ip address I should use or how can I get an IP from EC2 that I can use when running the server program ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it would depend on what your code does with those arguments and what you actually want your code to do…

if those parameters are being passed to [`socket.bind()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind) and you want it to listen for "all" incoming connections, then just pass an empty string for the host, e.g:

```
my_server.py '' 8888
```

might do the right thing.  otherwise, if this process is being proxied by something else (common in the web world, suggested by your port number 8888) you might still want to pass `127.0.0.1` (i.e. `localhost`) and then let the proxy do its stuff.

the other reason it might be failing is because that port is already in use by another program/service on that machine